# dashboard not displaying network and object store

Tags: openstack

After installing OpenStack (DevStack), I logged in to the dashboard. I could find only two tabs there (compute and orchestration) but not network and object store, though I have logged in as admin. Checked the keystone services, couldnt find swift and neutron services, so I just created those services and now it list there as shown below:

```
[stack@openstack devstack]$ keystone service-list
+---------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------------------+
|                id                |   name   |      type      |    description |
+---------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------------------+
| 2cbf320ab83d4177a71d97ea478404f8 |  cinder  |   volume  |Cinder Volume Service|
| b8d632ae79b34d95ac1f44738ac7eef0 | cinderv2 |  volumev2 |Cinder Volume Service V2  |
| b54f6814b6c449678118870d8492f93d |   ec2    |      ec2  |EC2 Compatibility Layer   |
| fc9b9806dfe74b89b600c178cc0e1812 |  glance  |     image |Glance Image Service    |
| 26a9b4ecc64a4749bfbd7872ef8e9500 | heat| orchestration  |Heat Orchestration Service |
| c3ec7483de44428691e96ed119e80121|heat-cfn|cloudformation|Heat CloudFormation Service|
| 62c9b47524ab4f139d54e7688c853cfb | keystone | identity |Keystone Identity Service  |
| 3dc65bcd40bf49d59c42c49a724c7563 | neutron  | network  |   Network Service       |
| d8e71222de334250903ddfa9c319db34 |   nova   | compute  |  Nova Compute Service    |
| 2573faf8148f455381fbffc5ca2726c2 |  novav3  | computev3|  Nova Compute Service V3   |
| cac5203d66aa4f309004c833e14abe4f |    s3    |   s3     |            S3             |
| 453c3a1a0f2c4652a076a6b6c7fcbe51 |  swift   |object-store| Object Store Service    |
+------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

From here (http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide-admin/content/log_in_dashboard.html) I can see that for admin user it must show the other two tabs as well (in projects) and in admin all these 3 are missing (Resource Usage, Networks, Routers).

As I am a beginner in Openstack I am not sure what to check or how to proceed? Can Someone please support me?

Answer (score 1):

That's because other services such as Swift, Cinder and Neutron are not installed. It's not enough just to add services in Keystone.
Devstack ships with Nova-network by default. If you want Neutron, you need to enable it explicitly:

From https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/NeutronDevstack

```
[[local|localrc]]
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service neutron
```

Comment: These services are already enabled in the localrc file.

Comment: Can you please post your localrc file?